# ¿Cómo validar un dato de un array en una consulta con PDO?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, datatables, pdo

en el día de hoy estoy pidiendo una ayuda, ya que quiero mandar un dato validado a datatable mediante AJAX pero con PDO y no con MySqli, sucede que quiero validar que si la columna "estado" de mi tabla usuarios es igual a 1 pues que se me marque ACTIVO y si es igual a 0 que se me marque INACTIVO, eso lo logré con MySqli y lo mandé a Ajax y me funcionó excelente, pero lo quiero hacer con PDO y no se como hacerlo. Simplemente me manda el array tal y como lo hala y me lo muestra tal y como lo hala. Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor lo apreciaría bastante.

Como lo tengo y me funciona sin PDO:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT u.id, u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.email, r.nombre_grupo, u.estado, u.fecha_registro FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN grupos_usuarios r ON u.grupo = r.id");
        $tabla = "";

        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            if ($data['estado'] == 1) {
                    $estado = "<span class='badge badge-pill badge-success'>ACTIVO</span>";
            } elseif ($data['estado'] == 0) {
                $estado = "<span class='badge badge-pill badge-danger'>INACTIVO</span>";
            } else {
                $estado = "<span class='bagde badge-pill badge-warning'>ERROR</span>";
            }
            $tabla = '{
                "id":"'.$data['id'].'",
                "nombre":"'.$data['nombre']. " " .$data['apellido'].'",
                "usuario":"'.$data['usuario'].'",
                "email":"'.$data['email'].'",
                "grupo":"'.$data['nombre_grupo'].'",
                "estado":"'.$estado.'",
                "fecha_registro":"'.$data['fecha_registro'].'"
            },';
        }
        $tabla = substr($tabla,0, strlen($tabla) - 1);
echo '{"data":['.$tabla.']}';
```

Como lo tengo en PDO y no me funciona igual que el anterior:

```
$sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.nombre, u.apellido, u.usuario, u.email, r.nombre_grupo, u.estado, u.fecha_registro FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN grupos_usuarios r ON u.grupo = r.id");
        $sql->execute();
        $data=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo mediante la misma consulta SQL con la clausula `CASE`.

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.nombre, 
    u.apellido, 
    u.usuario, 
    u.email, 
    r.nombre_grupo, 
    CASE
        WHEN u.estado = 1 THEN 'ACTIVO'
        WHEN u.estado = 2 THEN 'INACTIVO'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END as estado, 
    u.fecha_registro 
FROM 
    usuarios u 
INNER JOIN grupos_usuarios r ON u.grupo = r.id"
```

Comment: Muchas graciasa amigo.